# Como converter uma string html em objeto jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

Como converter uma *string* HTML em um objeto jQuery?

```
var objeto = '<div id="minhaDiv"><span id="meuSpan">Span</span></div>';
```

Comment: Podes explkcar melhor o que queres ter/fazer com esse objeto jQuery? (para ser mais claro o que procuras)

Comment: @Sergio eu tenho uma chamada AJAX que retorna uma string que será inserida no meu DOM. Gostaria de fazer uma pesquisa (usando o find) antes de adicioná-lo no DOM ao invés de adicionar e ter que fazer a pesquisa no DOM inteiro.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Muito simples, apenas instancie o jQuery passando o HTML como parâmetro.

```js
var teste = $('<div id="minhaDiv"><span id="meuSpan">Span</span></div>').find("span").text();
$("#result").html(teste);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Você pode usar `innerHTML`  nativo.
Exemplo

```
var objeto = '<div id="minhaDiv"><span id="meuSpan">Span</span></div>';
document.getElementById("ID_DIV").innerHTML = objeto ;
```

Ou pode usar `JQuery`:

```
var objeto = '<div id="minhaDiv"><span id="meuSpan">Span</span></div>';
$("#ID_DIV").html(objeto );
```

Answer (score -3):

body{
background-color: #082767;
}
#teste{
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
background-image: url(logolc.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
}
#teste1{
width: 400px;
height: 150px;
background-image: url(logolc.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#teste2{
width: 400px;
height: 150px;
background-image: url(logolc.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#teste3{
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
background-image: url(logolc.png);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}